# $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-Invariant tensor associated to irreducible representations

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I'm trying to understand the $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ irreducible representation.

It is known that any irreducible representation $\pi : \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \xrightarrow{} GL(V)$, with $V$ finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to the representation
$\pi_m : \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \xrightarrow{} GL(\mathbb{V}_m)$ where $\mathbb{V}_m$ are the homogenuous polinomial on $\mathbb{C}^2$ of degree $m=\dim(V)-1$.
In particular, by using Clebsch–Gordan theory for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ it is possible to decompose spaces as the space of symmetric and skew symmetric tensor over $\mathbb{V}_m$ into irreducibles.

In particular, the abstract irreducible decomposition of $S^2 \mathbb{V}_2$ (the space of symmetric two tensor) is $S^2 \mathbb{V}_2=\mathbb{V}_4 \oplus \mathbb{V}_0$

I'm puzled by the following sentence: "*the $\mathbb{V}_0$ factor indicates that there exists a unique (up to scale) sl(2; C)-invariant symmetric bilinear
form g = (·, ·) on $\mathbb{V}_2$.*"

More generally in $\mathbb{V}_m$ if $m$ is even we have a symmetric bilinear form, while if $m$ is odd we have a skwe symmetric bilinear form.

I know that such form is obtained by taking the higest weight element in $\mathbb{V}_0$  in the decomposition of $S^2 \mathbb{V}_m$ or $\Lambda^2 \mathbb{V}_m$ (in the basis given by standard $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ triple) and applying to it the interwinding $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow (\mathbb{C}^2)^*$, but i can't figure out why such form has to be invariant and why it is unique (up to a constant). What is the connection between $\mathbb{V}_0$ and the $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-invariant forms?

Comment: It's invariant because $\mathbb{V}_0$ is a trivial representation and unique up to a constant because $\mathbb{V}_0$ is 1-dimensional. Note you have said highest weight element but this is unnecessary there is only 1 element in $\mathbb{V}_0$ up to scale and it has weight $0$.

Comment: the space of symmetric bilinear forms on $V_2$ is $S^2 (V_2^*)$, so it would be more natural to decompose the latter space to irreducible components. However, we have an $sl(2)$-equivariant isomorphism $V_2 \cong V_2^*$, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @user8268 Note that any time we have a copy of the trivial rep in $S^2V$ we will have one in $S^2V^* = (S^2V)^*$ (likewise for $\bigwedge^2V$ and also true for higher powers). Then a non-degenerate invariant bilinear form gives a $\mathfrak{g}$-equivariant isomorphism $V \cong V^*$ in these cases regardless. In other words all reps with non-degenerate invariant bilinear forms are self-dual (and vice-versa). We can prove the bilinear form is non-degenerate by applying Schur's lemma.